# Sed line to remove unnecessary spaces is deleting line ends too & other strange new line issue

Tags: windows, bash, sed, cygwin

I have to deal with an output from a command. Just plain text. What I want is to remove unnecessary spaces by using

```
sed 's/  */ /g'
```

But it's doing it wrong - it seems to remove new line characters as well...

The other problem is about the $ character representing the 'new line'.

When I'm writing sth like this:

```
sed 's/$/FOO/g'
```

It is really replacing all the new line chars with the word FOO.
So its basically like:

```
text
text
text
```

Is converted to

```
textFOOtextFOOtext
```

The problem starts when 2 new lines occur. The text:

```
text

text
```

Is converted to:

```
textFOOFOOtext
```

BUT -- absolutely no SED line is able to convert the 2 new lines into one. I tried everything I found on the web.

How do I remove that additional new line?

Comment: You have `\r` in your lines. Use `dos2unix` to convert to unix format first.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps:

```
tr -s ' ' < File
```

This will change multiple spaces to single space, if thats what u want